# JQUERY Sortable - Detect li Item Hover Over Another li In The Same List

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I wondered if anyone had any ideas on how to detect if a sortable li item when being dragged is hovering over another li item in the same list? The reason i want to detect this is so that if one li item is dropped on to another it will create a sub list under the li that has been dropped on to.

I have tried many ways my self but cant seem to get it right. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Andy

Comment: You should get the element the draggable is dropped on then !

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am not sure what you mean... could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can make elements within your list [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) too:

```
$item.droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) { ... },
    out: function (event, ui) { ... },
    drop: function (event, ui) { ... },
    greedy: true,
    hoverClass: 'highlight'
});
```

$item can either be the list elements in your sorted list (e.g. the li in an ul) or some element within your li, like a div, which can avoid unexpected hover detection. The events will be triggered when a dragged element from your sortable passes into and out of the droppable. Drop is probably the most useful for what you want though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem  with yours and I have found a solution here: http://a.shinynew.me/post/4641524290/jquery-ui-nested-sortables
The idea is that you don't detect when is over another li item but you use sortable  connectWith

```
<div id="example5">
<ul>
     <li >Item 1
        <ul>
            <li >Item 1 1<ul></ul></li>
            <li >Item 1 2<ul></ul></li>
            <li >Item 1 3<ul></ul></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li >Item 2<ul></ul></li>
     <li >Item 3<ul></ul></li>
     <li >Item 4<ul></ul></li>
</ul>
```

and the javascript:

```
$("#example5 ul").sortable({
            connectWith: "#example5 ul",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"});
```